# Correctly read binary data encoded in variable-lengths

Tags: matlab, binary, binary-data, variable-length

I'm trying to read a binary data file containing time-series data in Matlab.

Sample data: `[23,-10,47,19,-417,-434,-1,29,11,22,23,6,18,13,-383]`

Command: `fopen(filename,'r','ieee-le');`

When I read the data in int8 format and compared to the ground truth, I realized for abs(data)<128, the data is stored in 1 byte, and when abs(data)>128, the data is stored in 2 bytes. And data of either lengths are intermixed together. e.g. for the sample data above, the data I read in int8 would be

[23,-10,47,19,**95,-2**,**78,-2**,-1,29,11,22,23,6,18,13,**-127,-2**]

Without prior knowledge of the true data, I would not have known that I should interpret the two bytes (marked in bold) together as one data point.

The digits in the two-bytes data points can also occur in the one-byte data points, so there's no obvious rule I can separate the two.

Am I reading the data correctly and is there any info I could use to correctly read the data?

Comment: Firstly, Please provide details about how the data is stored in the file (share a snapshot of the file). The file data format will help us understand how to interpret the data. 


Secondly, is it possible to save data in CSV file, the comma will help identify individual entities in the file

Comment: If your data is separated by commas, yo can read each element separately and check if it would fit in int8 or int16 and then store them accordingly.

Comment: But matlab does not allow different data formats in one array. (like int8 and int16 in a single array. It is not supported)

Comment: Can you just read everything as an `int16`? How is the data being written such that it's dumping mixed types into your binary data file? It doesn't seem like _any_ program could be expected to guess the per-element data type unless there's some sort of defined schema